# Scatterplot graph in R

Tags: r, csv, plot

I am trying to build a scatter plot, but I am getting 9 sub-graphs (imgur.com/XtsArW6). The input data is in CSV format [1]. I want the headers will be in the X axis and the values will be in the Y axis. How I do build a single scatter plot where the column names will be in the X axis, and the values will be in the Y axis?

[1] Data in `input.csv`

```
Roundrobin,Roundrobin1,Roundrobin2
159,203,186
169,213,145
142,235,124
```

[2] My R script

```
my_data <- read.csv("input.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

plot(my_data)
box()
```

[3] the output of the `dput(my_data)`.

```
structure(list(Roundrobin = c(159L, 169L, 142L), Roundrobin1 = c(203L, 213L, 235L), Roundrobin2 = c(186L, 145L, 124L)), .Names = c("Roundrobin", "Roundrobin1 "Roundrobin2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: what is your problem? loading your dataset? or producing the plot? what kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Why do you use the package "gdata" in this script? Also, it would be interesting that the example was reproducible.

Comment: what happens if you remove the pdf call? Do you get the barplot?

Comment: The `input.csv` contains the data in [1].  The output that I get is 9 graphs, so this is not what I want. If you run my script with my input data, you will get what I have.

Comment: Unsure it answer what you're trying to accomplish, but reading `?barplot` there's a names.arg, using it like this gives something like what I think is what you wish: `barplot(tdf,names.arg=rownames(tdf))` (with `tdf<-t(my_data)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You had an error in your dput, also suggested an edit)

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot)
my_data$ID <- seq.int(nrow(my_data)
melted <- melt(my_data,id=c("ID"))
ggplot(melted)+geom_point(aes(x=ID,y=value,color=factor(variable)))
```

[image: plot]

a slightly more fancy version including captions

```
ggplot(melted)+
geom_point(aes(x=ID,y=value,color=factor(variable))) +
xlab("X Axis Label")+
ylab("Y Axis Label") + 
scale_color_manual(name="Round robins",labels=c("1","2","3"),values=c("red","green","blue"))
```

version without ggplot

```
my_data$ID <- seq.int(nrow(my_data)
melted <- melt(my_data,id=c("ID"))
plot(melted$ID,melted$value,col=factor(melted$variable))
```

[image]

Comment: What you say it is not working. I get 9 graphs like this (http://imgur.com/XtsArW6).

Comment: I understood that this was your goal *but I am not getting 9 sub-graphs*. What do you want to achieve

Comment: I want a single scatter plot where the column names will be in the X axis, and the values will be in the Y axis.

Comment: Sorry forgot one line.

Comment: You solution with `ggplot` is ok now. But I would like to know how do I change the axis label, change the name to the label `factor(variable)`, and put the background of the graph in white with Y lines in black?

Comment: I added the column labels.

Comment: I still have some questions:
1. how I remove the X values from the graph (1.0,2.0,3.0)? 2. how can I put all the Y values in a single column? 3. can I put the background of the graph as white and the lines in the background in white?. 4. Can I add multiple `csv` files that have input data into a single graph?